# "Old" comic book - Batglare leaves new Justice Leaguer speechless

Tags: story-identification, dc, comics, batman

I was reading issue #60 of *Injustice 2*, and Booster Gold made quite a point about Batman:

[image: Booster Gold criticizes Batman]

> BOOSTER GOLD: Oh God! That guy. You know what? Bats claims he has no powers, but that's @#$%. His superpower is filling his fellow heroes with crippling insecurities. Seriously, every single Robin gets a pair of tights and an inferiority complex.

To which someone replied, in the comments:

> I do remember a thing from a LONG time ago, where the Flash and a newcomer to the JL (I want to say it was the Ray, but been too long) were chatting, with the new guy trying to understand why the Batman was considered such a badass since he was pretty much just a normal guy and had no superpowers. He then turned and and realized that Batman was right behind him looking right at him. Batman leaves and then the guy turns back to the Flash, who is just smiling.
>
> Flash then asks "You understand now?.
>
> He answered. "Yes."
>
> It was great.
>
> <sub>[Source](http://disq.us/p/1sv9qoi) (WARNING: NSFW ads, *Injustice 2* spoilers)</sub>

This seems like an(other) epic Batglare scene. I've waited some days to see if someone replied to the guy, identifying said comic, but no luck so far. For those who don't know what the Batglare is, here's a self-explanatory video:

I've searched around for Batglare occurrences in Silver and Bronze Ages, since the guy said it was a long time ago - but then again, "a long time" is relative. Then again, no luck.

Unfortunately, I don't have much more info than what was posted in the comment above... No replies there so far.

Comment: Most likely timeframe is mid-1980s, during the run where Keith Giffen and JM DeMatteis were writing the League. *Justice League*/Justice League International* issues before 20 are the most likely candidates, although later issues (it become *Justice League America* around issue 28, and gained a companion title, *Justice League Europe*). *JLE* included the Flash, so it might actually have shown up there.

Comment: @RDFozz duly noted. I did a quick browsing of _JLE_, but nothingshowed up. I'll go back to it when I have more time, but still, it's  a start! Thanks!

Comment: The Ray joined *Justice League Task Force* with issue #0; I skimmed that, and the next 5 issues (17-21), and the start of the 1987 *Justice League* / *Justice League International* run (Annual #1 and issues #1-16). There are at least a couple of Batglare moments in the first few issues of that, but none matching the one you want.